# Include label for each time step to allow gradient flow in LSTM

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning

Say I want to do a [many-to-one](http://karpathy.github.io/2015/05/21/rnn-effectiveness/) classification task such as sentiment analysis with a sequence of ~100 elements using a [LSTM](http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/lstm.html). Might it help to train the network using a many-to-many setup instead to allow the gradients to flow more easily to the initial elements in the long sequence? Each $y_t$ would just be a replica of the true value $y$.